# Target closest class .click jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I would like to apply `slideToggle` to only the class that is closest to the trigger image. I do not wish to have multiple ID's to run multiple versions of `slideToggle`.

I tried using `.closest` but to no avail

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/12/

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `closest()`?

Comment: The way how you implement this simple interaction is wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I accepted @Karl-André as he was the first one to come up with the chosen solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest` is not a parent of your image. Try using this :

```
$(this).closest('section').find('.content').slideToggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/16/

Answer (score 2):

Should do it:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('section').find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/13/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/17/)

Other option for cases when `.content` is not next item

```
$('.image').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('section').find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/19/)

Comment: thanks, is there a way of specifying this to only apply to `class="content"` The reason I ask is that there may be occasions that the content did is not the `.next` item

Comment: @TheApptracker: I just created an example taking into account what you said. I realized that my example is the same as Karl-André Gagnon's one. You might want to accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LstNS/15/)**

`.closest()` alone won't work because that only looks up in the DOM. You need to go up one level to the `<h3>` element and then select the next element, `<div class="content">`. You can also substitue `.closest('h3')` for `.parent()` in my example. Also, in your case, `.next('.content')` would be equivalent to `.next()`.

Comment: thanks, this seems to fail if `.content` is not the `.next` item. Is there a way of targeting the class as aposed to the next?

Comment: Right, by specifying `.content`, `.next` will only be applied if the next element has that class.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

I use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function to get to the same 'level' as the content, in this case the h3 is selected. Next i'll search for the closest [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) with the class content. It will not search further when it has found the right class.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/12/)**